# Add parentheses if argument has subscript

Tags: macros, conditionals

I'm looking for the way to create new command

```
\newcommand{\transpose}[1]{#1^T}.
```

But what is important here I want the command to check if the argument has super- or subscript and add parentheses if necessary. So it should do

```
#1 == D => \newcommand{\transpose}[1]{#1^T}
#1 == D_1 => \newcommand{\transpose}[1]{\left(#1\right)^T}
```

I hope it's clear. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Should we allow for cases where `#1` merely expands to something with such sub/superscripts?

Answer (score 6):

This reads the argument as a list of items, with `^` and `_` as item delimiters (parsing separators).  If either/both are present, the list length will exceed one.  I then use the list length to decide whether or not to add parens.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\transpose[1]{%
  \setsepchar{_||^}%
  \readlist\mymat{#1}%
  \ifnum\mymatlen>1\left(#1\right)^T\else#1^T\fi%
}
\begin{document}  
\[
\transpose{D}
\]
\[
\transpose{D_1}
\]
\[
\transpose{D^x}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A single expansion upon the argument, in the form of

```
\newcommand\transpose[1]{%
  \setsepchar{_||^}%
  \expandafter\readlist\expandafter\mymat\expandafter{#1}%
  \ifnum\mymatlen>1\left(#1\right)^T\else#1^T\fi%
}
```

would allow some embedded cases to be properly digested, for example,

```
\def\myvar{A_x}
\[
\transpose{\myvar}
\]
```

[image]