# Add parentheses if double superscript

Tags: superscripts, xparse, parenthesis

I'd like to set up a macro able to add parenthesis if the argument has already one superscript. It similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394841/add-parentheses-if-argument-has-subscript), unfortunately the compilation of the following MWE doesn't end…

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dans}{mG{\BbbR}e{^}}{%
    \ensuremath{#1\in\IfValueTF{#3}{{\left(#2\right)}^{#3}}{#2}}%
    }
\NewDocumentCommand{\Dans}{mG{\BbbR}e{^}}{%
    \setsepchar{_||^}%
    \readlist\mymat{#2}%
    \ensuremath{#1\in\IfValueTF{#3}{\ifnum\mymatlen>1\left(#2\right)^{#3}\else#2^{#3}\fi}{#2}}%
    }


\begin{document}
    \dans{x}, \dans{(x, y)}{\BbbC^2}, \dans{(x, y)}{\BbbC}^2, \dans{(x, y)}{\BbbC^\star}^2

    %\Dans{x}, \Dans{(x, y)}{\BbbC^2}, \Dans{(x, y)}{\BbbC}^2, \Dans{(x, y)}{\BbbC^\star}^2
\end{document}
```

Problem arises when uncommenting the line.

[image]

Comment: Do you plan to use also subscripts in the optional argument to `\dans`?

Comment: This may occur… At least within the `G` argument.

Comment: And what should happen with `\dans{(x,y)}{\BbbR_+}^2`? Do you want parentheses or not?

Comment: Actually I won't have this problem since I choose to denote `\BbbR^+` and `\BbbR^{+\star}`! But `\BbbR_+^2` is readable without parenthesis, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `expl3` to check for an `^` inside of the second argument with `\tl_if_in:nnTF`, one could add the braces based on this test:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \NBur_superscript:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { ^ }
      { \left( #1 \right) }
      { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\dans}{mG{\BbbC}e{^}}
  {%
    \ensuremath
      {%
        #1\in\IfValueTF{#3}{\NBur_superscript:n{#2}^{#3}}{#2}%
      }%
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\dans{x}^2,
\dans{x}{A}^2,
\dans{x}{A^*}^2
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you hide the superscript inside a macro above test won't find it. A possible solution would be to fully expand the argument, in order to look for superscript chars then:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand\Test{A^*}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_in:nnTF { xnTF }
\cs_new:Npn \NBur_superscript:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_in:xnTF { #1 } { ^ }
      { \left( #1 \right) }
      { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\dans}{mG{\BbbC}e{^}}
  {%
    \ensuremath
      {%
        #1\in\IfValueTF{#3}{\NBur_superscript:n{#2}^{#3}}{#2}%
      }%
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\dans{x}^2,
\dans{x}{A}^2,
\dans{x}{A^*}^2
\dans{x}{\Test}^2
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above still might fail, e.g. if the superscript is hidden inside something unexpandable or if something shouldn't be expanded there (the former leading to wrong behaviour, the latter possibly to an error or really bad behaviour). The latter should be rare with normal use cases (I hope).