# Double Superscript Error with Macro Adding a Superscript

Tags: macros, superscripts

I found a lots of questions asking how to add a superscript to a variable defined with a superscript but none for how to do it the other way around.

My macro is `\newcommand{\trsp}[1]{#1^T}` and I want to apply it to e.g. `\trsp{M^{-1}}`.

How do I avoid a Double Superscript error ?

Comment: the simplest way is to define `\trsp` as `{#1}^T`  but that has some consequences on spacing in all cases. So alternative is to explicitly test or have a separate command for teh transposed inverse

Comment: If you want something automatic, have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481888/151808).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\def\trsp#1{{#1}^T}`. The key is to use `{#1}` instead `#1` in the body of the macro. You can use `\newcommand` too, if you are using LaTeX.